# array values to nested array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how I can use the values an indexed array as path for another array. I'm exploding a string to an array, and based on all values in that array I'm looking for a value in another array.

Example:

```
$haystack['my']['string']['is']['nested'] = 'Hello';
$var = 'my@string@is@nested';
$items = explode('@', $var);

// .. echo $haystack[... items..?]
```

The number of values may differ, so it's not an option to do just `$haystack[$items[0][$items[1][$items[2][$items[3]]`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop -

```
$haystack['my']['string']['is']['nested'] = 'Hello';
$var = 'my@string@is@nested';
$items = explode('@', $var);

$temp = $haystack;
foreach($items as $v) {
    $temp = $temp[$v]; // Store the current array value
}
echo $temp;
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/412451)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Works like a charm. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop to grab each subsequent nested array. I.e:

```
$haystack['my']['string']['is']['nested'] = 'Hello';
$var = 'my@string@is@nested';
$items = explode('@', $var);
$val = $haystack;
foreach($items as $key){
    $val = $val[$key];
}
echo $val;
```

Note that this does no checking, you likely want to check that `$val[$key]` exists.

Example here: http://codepad.org/5ei9xS91

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Works like a charm, neat solution. @b0s3 was just a bit earlier. Can only accept one answer. +1

Comment: @ben Nope first answer was posted by Jim

Comment: Strange, my browser is telling me otherwise ;) Nonetheless, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use a recursive function:

```
function extractValue($array, $keys)
{
    return empty($keys) ? $array : extractValue($array[array_shift($keys)], $keys) ; 
}

$haystack = array('my' => array('string' => array('is' => array('nested' => 'hello'))));
echo extractValue($haystack, explode('@', 'my@string@is@nested'));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond. A working solution has been provided, while yours works too. Have a nice day. +1